# Items in ComboBox disappear

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I have the following problem creating custom cell factory of a ComboBox from an FXML file created with Scene Builder in JavaFX:
I created a custom cell factory of Labels. It works fine when the user clicks on the items. The y are displayed in the "button" area. But when the user wants to click on another items the previously clicked item is gone.
[image: Image of the disappeared item]

Here is the code of the combobox cell factory:

```
idCardOnlineStatusComboBox.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Label>, ListCell<Label>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<Label> call(ListView<Label> param) {
               final ListCell<Label> cell = new ListCell<Label>() {   
                    @Override public void updateItem(Label item, 
                        boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if(item != null || !empty) {
                                setGraphic(item);
                            }
                        }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    });
```

I suppose there is a problem in the cell factory but i can't figure out where it is.

I extract the combobox from the fxml with this code:

```
@FXML private ComboBox idCardOnlineStatusComboBox;
```

then i fill the combobox with this:

```
idCardOnlineStatusComboBox.getItems().addAll(
            new Label(Resource.getStringFor("MainForm.Pane.MenuBar.Vortex.OnlineStatus.Online.Title"), new ImageView(onlineImg)),
            new Label(Resource.getStringFor("MainForm.Pane.MenuBar.Vortex.OnlineStatus.Away.Title"), new ImageView(awayImg)),
            new Label(Resource.getStringFor("MainForm.Pane.MenuBar.Vortex.OnlineStatus.DoNotDisturb.Title"), new ImageView(doNotDisturbImg)),
            new Label(Resource.getStringFor("MainForm.Pane.MenuBar.Vortex.OnlineStatus.Invisible.Title"), new ImageView(offlineImg)),
            new Label(Resource.getStringFor("MainForm.Pane.MenuBar.Vortex.OnlineStatus.Offline.Title"), new ImageView(offlineImg))
            );
```

Comment: is all your code here? Please, post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) where we can try and see the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disappearing behavior may be a bug. You can file it to JavaFX Jira, and let the Oracle guys decide it further. Additionally you can investigate the `ComboBox.setCellFactory(...)` source code for the reason of this behavior and find workaround. But my suggestion is to use the ComboBox Cell's (`ListCell`) internal `Labelled` component, instead of yours:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Label item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null && !empty) {
        setText(item.getText());
        setGraphic(item.getGraphic());
    } else {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    }
}
```

Note the else part of the code, cover all use cases when writing an if-statement.